# All downloaded maps have Seed 0?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have MCPE 1.0.4.0, and I wanted a.good looking medieval castle map. So I went to MCPEDL and downloaded a few maps. The problem is that whenever I extract them and place them in the Minecraftworlds folder, and open the game, they are shown to have Seed 0. Always.

I have Lava A97, Android 6.0.

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the world was made in an earlier version with another seed storing system

Comment: Yeah, it was from 0.8.0 or something thereabout